# Performance benefits using gRPC to communicate with Postgresql from Web?

Tags: postgresql, architecture

Standard REST server is rather simple to understand and get up and running. But a gRPC server that do the same thing seems to be more complicated.

[image]

1. Are there many that uses the concept web > gRPC > Postgresql?
2. Will there be any performance difference in the real world?

Comment: While this question may be "opinion based" or whatever, it's not a "[`what colour should my database be`](https://koolinus.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/media_httpdilbertcomd_jfuku-scaled1000.gif)" question! As long as the discussion is about **technical** merits, then I feel that this question should be neither downvoted nor closed!

Comment: What part is the "opinion based" part?

Comment: `Are there any benefits with gRPC in THIS case compared to REST?` for example. You already have 2 close votes - 1 of which is on the basis that your question is "primarily opinion based"... I like the question and feel that many are closed for that reason, when a good **technical** exchange could be stimulated by the question - your question in particular. Read the FAQ - check out my profile which has several articles on how to answer questions here.

Comment: Excuse me for being unclear. I am asking for something like real world benefits of actual speed. Not opinion based speed. I am asking for benefits of less crashes or higher security. Not opinion based. Or is this the wrong forum for questions regarding how to use gRPC in communication between web and sql database?

Comment: `I am asking for benefits of less crashes or higher security.` I know - and I appreciate this. However, (some) people here seem to think that any question which is not **totally** objective (i.e. `how do I get result x from SQL?`) is off-topic. I do not concur - I feel that debate and **technical opinion/guidance/knowledge** as long as it's backed up by references (urls, benchmarks &c. - take a look at my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/235076/34007)) is valid on this site - as long as it doesn't degenerate into "My daddy's RAM is bigger than yours"... Your question is OK by me!

Comment: I have been on SO for several years and asked both stupid and well received questions. For some reason are questions about Golang repeatedly downvoted. Regardless how asked. Because Golang and gRPC are relatively new to everybody? And at least I do not know exactly what or how I should ask. `Your question is OK by me!`. Thank You!

Comment: `Because Golang and gRPC are relatively new to everybody?` That's an opinon based issue if ever I saw one! :-) Some may feel it's opinion, some may feel it belongs on StackExchange or SoftwareRecs? I know that Go is becoming very important in the database area with more and more tools and even products (CockroachDB - a deadly db!!! TiKV also) written in it or using it. I try and steer clear of the politics here (got burned early on when I was young, dumb and full of..(err..) you know what :-) ). Any tips I might have would be to ask definite questions: "Are there any benchmarks which show...?"

Comment: `Are there any benchmarks which show...`  Searching for "grpc golang postgresql" on SO gives 0 results "grpc web postgresql" gives 0 results. So my opinion is based on these facts :-) My statement was merely about the "concept" **web-grpc-sql** And benchmarking a motor at the lab always gives other results than real world...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (e.g. migrate it to a different site) because gRPC is not a database technology, per se, and Postgres, while mentioned in this question, is ancillary to it.  Frankly, I think you would have better luck with this question on Stack Overflow as I would suspect you'll find a higher number of users with gRPC experience than on dba.se.  Good question, wrong site, imo.

Comment: @John Eisbrener Thank you for your comments. I will move this to other forum. Though I think communicating with postgresql is not off topic. You can close this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm splitting hairs, but hopefully you get more traction on SO.

Comment: Given the picture you painted, the use (or non-use) of gRPC seems to play no role in the performance of the actual database query. And it also seems irrelevant which DBMS sits after the "SQL Query" part for the performance of the communication between the "Web JSON" part and the receiving of of the JSON. So this question indeed seems off-topic here.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name Well, you have answered the question, sort of. But it should be interesting to know  if this concept is used by others in the real word.